# autoconf computed include file name

Tags: include, autoconf, computed-values

Would anybody know if there's any way of computing the name of an included file in autoconf ?

I have a project capable of building one of several variants currently based on an identity defined in configure.ac - my aim is to be able to identify the variant from the CLI when autoconf/configure is run and include an m4 file if/as appropriate. AFAICT, only string literals are allowed as the filename in either the include or sinclude macro calls ... and it's now starting to drive me to distraction =:-O

Any help most gratefully received

DP

Comment: I think I have a better understanding of what you are trying to do now.  So how is this "identity" defined in `configure.ac`?  Is it in the shell scripting layer (e.g. a shell variable, `AC_ARG_WITH`, `AC_ARG_ENABLE`, et al.) or the m4sugar layer (e.g. `m4_define`, `m4_include`, `m4_sinclude` et al.)?  If it's defined in the shell scripting layer, it's already too late to do anything in m4 -- `configure` has already been written.

Comment: Thanx for that @ldav1s, you have confirmed my newly gained understanding of what's going on under the hood. FWIW, the option is passed in as a  configure option which means that I have to come up with an alternative solution to the problem. (I'd love to say that you've answered the question, but as a noob, don't know how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity is setup at `configure` runtime, not when `configure` is created.  Any m4 level (e.g. m4sugar) manipulation of `configure` will happen before then, so this doesn't look possible.